# Obtain Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization in Java

Tags: java, matrix

I have to do the Orthogonalization process using Gram-Schimdt so I can get A=QR. I'm working with the matrix columns as *double[]* and they are stored in an *ArrayList*, the thing is, I'm just calculating Q so I can do the rest which is easier once I got Q. But my problem is that when the program gets to add the finalArray, I don't know why the parameter *array* got modified and every vector in it is altered and obviously the result is wrong. What I'm doing wrong? (By the way, I can't use libraries of Java to solve this). Also I test the algorithm doing it with my own hands and it should works because I also print the result and notice where it got altered

```
/*
I should do Uk = (Vk - (Uk-1*Vk)*Uk-1 - ... - (U1*Vk)*Uk1)/||Uk|| 
Where ||Uk|| = Length of Uk

Vectors U own to finalArray and the V ones own to array 
*/
public ArrayList< double[] > gramSchmidt(ArrayList< double[] > array)
{
    ArrayList< double[] > finalArray= new ArrayList<>();

    //I set the first vector because it never changes, it's always the first vector of the array receive divided between it's length
    finalArray.add(multiplyScalarPerVector(1/(calculateVectorLength(array.get(0))), array.get(0)));
    //This last line is the one that modifies EVERYTHING in array and it shouldn't

    for(int i=1; i<array .size(); i++)
    {
        double[] newVector= substractVectors(array .get(i), proyection(finalArray.get(i-1),array .get(i)));
        for(int e=i-1;e>0;e--)
        {
            newVector= substractVectors(newVector, proyection(finalArray.get(e-1),array .get(i)));
        }
        newVector= multiplyScalarPerVector(1/(calculateVectorLength(newVector)), newVector);
        finalArray.add(newVector);
    }
    return finalArray;
}

//Obtain the (Uk-1*Vk)*Uk-1
public double[] proyection(double[] array1, double[] array2)
{
    double dotProductResult= dotProduct(array1,array2);
    double[] finalVector= multiplyScalarPerVector(dotProductResult, array1);
    return finalVector;
}

//To do Uk-1*Vk
public double dotProduct(double[] vector1, double[] vector2)
{
    double result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<vector1.length; i++)
    {
        result +=vector1[i]*vector2[i];
    }
    return result ;
}

public double[] multiplyScalarPerVector(double scalar, double[] vector)
{
    double[] newVector = new double[vector.length];
    for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
    {
        newVector[i] = scalar*vector[i];
    }
    return newVector;
}

public double[] substractVectors(double[] vector1, double[] vector2)
{
    double[] finalVector= new double[vector1.length];
    for(int i=0; i<vector1.length; i++)
    {
        finalVector[i] = vector1[i] - vector2[i];
    }
    return finalVector;
}

//Calculate the euclidean distance
public double calculateVectorLength(double[] vector)
{
    double result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
    {
        result +=Math.pow(vector[i], 2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(result );
}
```

Comment: Ok...Don't know why but it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign

```
double[] newVector= vector;
```

then you don't create a new object, but `newVector` and `vector` reference to the same object. `newVector` is not a new object it is a reference to the same object as `vector` references to.

This causes that in the loop

```
for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
{
    newVector[i] = scalar*vector[i];
}
```

`newVector` and `vector` are change alike. An assignment to `newVector[i]` changes also `vector[i]`, because they refer to the same object.

The same is the case when you do:

```
double[] finalVector= vector1;
for(int i=0; i<vector1.length; i++)
{
    finalVector[i] = vector1[i] - vector2[i];
}
```

Note, you don't create new vector objects with new content, but you change the input vector objects and return a reference to the changed objects.
Because of that you change source vector objects, which are still needed in the further calculation. This causes that the final result is not as it ought to be.

Create new objects to solve the issue:

```
double[] newVector= new double[vector.length];
```

```
double[] finalVector= new double[vector1.length];
```

See also [Java assigning object reference](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-assigning-object-reference/)